# trying to get data in a list, i getting a error : The named param is not define

Tags: flutter

i'm learned flutter and use a quizz game tutorial. The probleme is then i tried to get the question list in the a List, my debug console return me undefined_named_parameter. i'm tried different solution but I still have the same problem

that my code

```
import 'package:flutter/animation.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:quizz_app/models/question.dart';

//we use get pckage for our state management
class QuestionController extends GetxController
with SingleGetTickerProviderMixin {
late AnimationController _animationController;
late Animation _animation;
Animation get animation => _animation;
// ignore: prefer_final_fields
Iterable _question = sampleData
  .map((question) => Question(
      id: question['id'],
      answer: question['answer_id'],
      question: question['question'],
      options: question['option']))
  .toList();

 @override
 void onInit() {
 _animationController =
    AnimationController(duration: const Duration(seconds: 60), vsync: this);
_animation = Tween(begin: 1.0, end: 0.0).animate(_animationController)
  ..addListener(() {
    //update like setstate
    update();
  });
_animationController.forward();
super.onInit();
 }
 }
```

this is my question list

```
class Question {
final int id, answer;
final String question;
final List<String> options;

Question(this.id, this.answer, this.question, this.options);
}

const List sampleData = [
{
  "id": 1,
  "question":
    "Flutter is an open-source UI software development kit created by ______",
  "options": ['Apple', 'Google', 'Facebook', 'Microsoft'],
  "answer_index": 1,
  },
  {
   "id": 2,
   "question": "When google release Flutter.",
   "options": ['Jun 2017', 'Jun 2017', 'May 2017', 'May 2018'],
   "answer_index": 2,
 },
 {
  "id": 3,
  "question": "A memory location that holds a single letter or number.",
   "options": ['Double', 'Int', 'Char', 'Word'],
   "answer_index": 2,
   },
  {
"id": 4,
"question": "What command do you use to output data to the screen?",
"options": ['Cin', 'Count>>', 'Cout', 'Output>>'],
 "answer_index": 2,
 },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

```dart
question: question[question]
```

in

```dart
Iterable _question = sampleData
  .map((question) => Question(
      id: question['id'],
      answer: question['answer_id'],
      question: question[question], // This
      options: question['option']))
  .toList();
```

should be

```dart
question: question['question']
```

Comment: it not work i have same error

Comment: @PhilippeTankoano still the same issue?